# Unable to reference gradle.properties in script plugin

Tags: gradle, ivy, artifactory

I am creating a script plugin to reference the ivy repository holding my orgs gradle plugins.  My code right now is:

**repository.gradle**

```
repositories {
    ivy {
       credentials {
            username = artifactory_user
            password = artifactory_password
        }
        url 'https://ourUrl/artifactory/repoName'
        layout "pattern", {
            ivy '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml'
            artifact '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]'
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the build.gradle file,

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    apply from: https://ourUrl/assets/repository.gradle, to: buildscript
    dependencies { classpath group: 'ourGrp', name: 'artifactName', version: '1.0.0' }
}
```

In my gradle.properties file:

**gradle.properties**

```
artifactory_user=username
artifactory_password=password
```

The error message I recieve is this:

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
Could not find property 'artifactory_user' on Credentials [username: null].
```

Any suggestions for how I can resolve this?  I would like to avoid any further impact to the **build.gradle** file if possible.

Comment: Could you please try to refer to `artifactory_user` with `project. artifactory_user`?

Comment: The **gradle.properties** file is in my Gradle User Home, not the project home directory.  I have confirmed that the gradle user home is being picked up correctly in the build using --info.

Comment: Ok, just tried changing to that and I get the message:
     Could not find property 'project' on Credentials [username: null].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This exact question was asked in the gradle forums](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/accessing-project-properties-from-gradle-properties-in-buildscript-block#reply_15065153). I'll paste the working workaround so it won't get lost during relinking or something:

`repository.gradle:`

```
repositories {
    ivy {
       credentials {
            username = artifactory_user
            password = artifactory_password
        }
        url 'https://ourUrl/artifactory/repoName'
        layout "pattern", {
            ivy '[organization]/[module]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml'
            artifact '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]'
        }
    }
}
ext.extRepo = repositories
```

`build.gradle:`

```
buildscript {scriptHandler->
  apply from: 'https://ourUrl/assets/repository.gradle'
  repositories.addAll(extRepo)
```